# Action bar, use text as icon rather than image

Tags: android

I want to be able to display text rather than an icon in the action bar, is this possible?

Comment: Do you mean the home icon in the top left, or an action item on the right of the action bar?

Comment: Sorry I should have been clearer, I mean for action items

Comment: That works perfectly thanks, I feel stupid for not simply removing the reference to icon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to show a text action item in the right of the action bar, in your menu.xml layout, use the item `android:title`, and don't use the `android:icon` item.  Alternatively, if you want to switch between icon and text, set the `:showAsAction` field as needed.

If you're talking about the icon in the top left, you could just use a text image as your icon, or set `setDisplayShowHomeEnabled()` to false, and `setDisplayShowTitleEnabled()` to true.